# Manual pearson correlation in r

Tags: r, functional-programming, correlation

How would you create a function that manually calculates pearson correlation in r. I know that there is a native function called **cor**, but what if I want to apply the below equation in R to each combination of columns in a data frame, how would I do it?

[image]

I wish I knew how, but I believe it requires many for-loops, nested for-loops etc to make it happen and I am not that strong at programming yet. I hope someone will attempt such that a newbie like me can learn. Thanks

Example:

```
  set.seed(1)
  DF = data.frame(V1 = rnorm(10), V2=rnorm(10), V3=rnorm(10), V4=rnorm(10))

  #     V1    V2    V3    V4
  # V1  1.00 -0.38 -0.72 -0.24
  # V2 -0.38  1.00  0.60  0.18
  # V3 -0.72  0.60  1.00  0.08
  # V4 -0.24  0.18  0.08  1.00
```

Comment: no loops required. You can calculate sigmaX as sum(X) and sigmaXY as sum(X*Y) and build the whole equation up

Comment: please, give us a reproducible example of the input, and the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First write a helper function to calculate covariance:

```
v <- function(x,y=x) mean(x*y) - mean(x)*mean(y)
```

Then use it to calculate correlation:

```
my_corr <- function(x,y) v(x,y) / sqrt(v(x) * v(y))
```

Here's a quick check that it works correctly:

```
> my_corr(DF$V1, DF$V2)
[1] -0.3767034
> cor(DF$V1, DF$V2)
[1] -0.3767034
```

Note that calculating correlation this way is numerically unstable.

EDIT:

To apply it to all combinations of columns, use `outer` :

```
> outer(DF, DF, Vectorize(my_corr))

                  V1    V2    V3    V4
            # V1  1.00 -0.38 -0.72 -0.24
            # V2 -0.38  1.00  0.60  0.18
            # V3 -0.72  0.60  1.00  0.08
            # V4 -0.24  0.18  0.08  1.00
```

Comment: Doesn't work, when I insert my data frame my_corr(DF)` Remember it is a **data frame** where the function should work not on vectors.

Comment: But here you are defining your columns with $,  a function should be generalized  such that it finds columns by its own. What if you have 100 columns? How would you write that function?

Answer (score 0):

Well. You don't need to do this "manually", you just use....

```
cor(DF)
```

... which calculates r's for all combinations of columns.